# Javascript If /if else/ else - not sure what to use

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm not great at JS, but I've got some code here, and basically, I want the first round of code to execute for the RowIndex 1,2,3,4,5 and take the reaction time from 8000ms. If the rows are 6,7,8,9,10 then I want the reaction time to be taken from only 1500ms.

Here is the code I have:

```
gorillaTaskBuilder.onScreenStart((spreadsheet: any, rowIndex: number, screenIndex: number, row: any, container: string) => {
$('body').css('background-color', BACKGROUND_COLOUR);
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, span').css('color', TEXT_COLOUR);
if (row.display == _requiredFeedbackDisplay) {
    if (screenIndex == _requiredFeedbackScreen) {
        if (rowIndex == 1,2,3,4,5) {
            // Retrieve the reaction time from the store
            var lastRT: number = gorilla.retrieve(_RTKey, null, false);
            var roundedRT: number = Math.round(lastRT);
            var pointConvertedBlue: number = (8000 - roundedRT);
            // We now add the rounded reaction time to the screen
            $(container + _requiredFeedbackZoneSelector).html('<h1>' + '<p style="color: white;">' + 'You earned ' + pointConvertedBlue + ' points' + '</p> ' + '</h1>');
            // Using gorilla.refreshLayout here will make sure that everything is displayed nicely on the screen
            gorilla.refreshLayout();
            gorilla.metric({
                    trial_number: 'pointConvertedBlue',
                    response: pointConvertedBlue
        
 });
                else (rowIndex == 6,7,8,9,10) {
                        // Retrieve the reaction time from the store
                        var pointConvertedRed: number = (1500 - roundedRT);
                        // We now add the rounded reaction time to the screen
                        $(container + _requiredFeedbackZoneSelector).html('<h1>' + '<p style="color: white;">' + 'You earned ' + pointConvertedRed + ' points' + '</p> ' + '</h1>');
                        // Using gorilla.refreshLayout here will make sure that everything is displayed nicely on the screen
                        gorilla.refreshLayout();
                        gorilla.metric({
                            trial_number: 'pointConvertedRed',
                            response: pointConvertedRed
                        
                            
                        }
                     
        
    


                        });
```

If I delete the block of code starting from the else statement, the first block works fine. When I have both blocks together, the script only runs the second block of code. This is probably a really easy fix but I'm absolutely stuck haha.

Comment: Usually when you're going into 3 nested ifs you should refactor and break down the logic into separate functions, so it's not really a matter of using `if` or `else if` but rather how you can split the logic into manageable blocks that do a certain exact job.

Comment: `if ([6,7,8,9,10].includes(rowIndex))` and `if (rowIndex >= 6 && rowIndex <= 10)` are both valid approaches here.

Comment: You'll want to have a read about the [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in JavaScript to find out why what you wrote `if (rowIndex == 1,2,3,4,5)` is not a syntax error, but definitely doesn't do what you intended.  Basically expressions separated by commas evaluate to the last item in the comma chain.  Operator precedence is an issue here too because the `==` has higher precedence than the comma. so it's like `((rowIndex==1),(2),(3),(4),(5))`, which equals `5`. So it's like `if(5)` which is always true.

Answer (score 2):

To check if a number is within a range you would do a comparison check like this:

```js
if (i >= 1 && i <= 5)
```

The above code would be true if `i` was between 1 and 5 (inclusive).

Here's a runnable example that checks the ranges that you are using:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (i >= 1 && i <= 5) {
    document.write("a");
  } else if (i >= 6 && i <= 10) {
    document.write("b");
  }
}
```

---

To create a variable and assign a value to it, replace this:

```js
var roundedRT: number = Math.round(lastRT);
```

With

```js
var roundedRT = Math.round(lastRT);
```

You'll need to use the same syntax for the other variables as well.

---

It seems very odd that `pointConvertedBlue` is a string on one line and a variable on the next line. I'd recommend checking that:

```js
gorilla.metric({
    trial_number: 'pointConvertedBlue',
    response: pointConvertedBlue        
});
```

---

Unless this is some variant of JavaScript or something weird going on, you shouldn't be declaring the variable types for the function parameters. So replace all of the stuff like this:

```js
rowIndex: number
```

With

```js
rowIndex
```

---

Aside from those items, you'll need to match the brackets `(){}` throughout the code. That's essential for it to work correctly. I see multiple problems with that.

---

I would also recommend fixing the indentation as well. This isn't essential, but helps to make the code more readable and maintainable. It's fine up to `gorilla.metric({` and then needs fixing for all the lines after that.

---

You may also want to remove the `spreadsheet` parameter, because it isn't being used.

Answer (score 0):

first at all, you have an extra ";" before the else statement. It must be replaced by a "}".
In addition to this, there are several problems of closing braces and parentheses.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have :number in your code, I'm guessing you are using Typescript.

I would first recommend using some guard if statements for the first two if statements.

from

```
if (row.display == _requiredFeedbackDisplay) {
    if (screenIndex == _requiredFeedbackScreen) {
```

to

```
if (row.display != _requiredFeedbackDisplay) return;
if (screenIndex != _requiredFeedbackScreen) return;
```

Now, the two lines aren't creating an indent, which makes our code look cleaner and easier to manage. Also notice that I replaced == with != so we leave the function if they don't match rather than continuing if they do match.

Now we can deal with the if...else if, statements.

```
if (rowIndex >= 1 && rowIndex <= 5) return 8000;
if (rowIndex >= 6 && rowIndex <= 10) return 1500;
```

Now we are checking if the rowIndex is between 1 and 2, and returning if it is. Then the same for between 6 and 10.

In the example I just return the numbers you specified in your question, but you can convert them to normal if statements, or create a function to handle them.

```
function finishMessage(points: number, reactionTime: number): string {
  return `
    <h1>
        <p style="color: white;">
            You earned ${points - reactionTime} points 
        </p> 
    </h1>`;
}
```

Because the HTML is the same for both if statements, and the number being the only real difference, I have made a function, so we don't have to write duplicate code.

Our end code will look something like this:

```
function onScreenStart(rowIndex: number, screenIndex: number, row: any) {
  if (!row.display == _requiredFeedbackDisplay) return;
  if (screenIndex == _requiredFeedbackScreen) return;
  if (rowIndex >= 1 && rowIndex <= 5) return finishMessage(8000, reactionTime);
  if (rowIndex >= 6 && rowIndex <= 10) return finishMessage(1500, reactionTime);
}

function finishMessage(points: number, reactionTime: number): string {
  return `
    <h1>
        <p style="color: white;">
            You earned ${points - reactionTime} points 
        </p> 
    </h1>`;
}
```

As you can see, the code is a lot easier to read, while also being a lot simpler. If you have any questions, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

This was the code that ended up working. Thank you everyone for your guidance!! <3

```
    var _requiredDisplay = 'instructions';

// This variable controls which screen we want to check fullscreen
var _requiredScreen = 1;

var _requiredRTDisplay: string = 'Trial_Mouse';
var _requiredRTScreen: number = 1;
var _requiredFeedbackDisplay: string = 'Trial_Mouse';
var _requiredFeedbackScreen: number = 2;
var _requiredFeedbackZoneName: string = 'PointsEarned';
var _requiredFeedbackZoneSelector: string = ' .' + _requiredFeedbackZoneName;
var _RTKey: string = 'lastRT';
var _requiredRTDisplay2: string = 'Trial_Keyboard';
var _requiredRTScreen2: number = 1;
var _requiredFeedbackDisplay2: string = 'Trial_Keyboard';
var _requiredFeedbackScreen2: number = 2;
var _requiredFeedbackZoneName2: string = 'pointsEarned';
var _requiredFeedbackZoneSelector2: string = ' .' + _requiredFeedbackZoneName2;
var _RTKey2: string = 'lastRT';
var BACKGROUND_COLOUR = '#000000';
var TEXT_COLOUR = '#FFFFFF';
var TrialNumber: string = 'TrialNumer';



gorillaTaskBuilder.onScreenFinish((spreadsheet: any, rowIndex: number, screenIndex: number, row: any, container: string, correct: boolean) => {
            // Check to see if we're on the display and screen where we want to collect the reaction time
            if (row.display == _requiredRTDisplay) {
                if (screenIndex == _requiredRTScreen) {
                    // At the beginning of each screen, Gorilla starts a stopwatch.  We can read this stopwatch at the end of the screen to get the participants
                    // reaction time for that trial
                    var reactionTime: number = gorilla.readStopwatch();
                    // We now store the reaction time using the key we setup above
                    gorilla.store(_RTKey, reactionTime, false);
                }



            }

            if (row.display == _requiredRTDisplay2) {
                if (screenIndex == _requiredRTScreen2) {
                    // At the beginning of each screen, Gorilla starts a stopwatch.  We can read this stopwatch at the end of the screen to get the participants
                    // reaction time for that trial
                    var reactionTime: number = gorilla.readStopwatch();
                    // We now store the reaction time using the key we setup above
                    gorilla.store(_RTKey2, reactionTime, false);
                }
            });

        gorillaTaskBuilder.onScreenStart((spreadsheet: any, rowIndex: number, screenIndex: number, row: any, container: string) => {
            $('body').css('background-color', BACKGROUND_COLOUR);
            $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, span').css('color', TEXT_COLOUR);
            if (row.display == _requiredFeedbackDisplay) {
                if (screenIndex == _requiredFeedbackScreen) {
                    if (row.TrialNumer >= 1 && row.TrialNumer <= 30) {
                        // Retrieve the reaction time from the store
                        var lastRT: number = gorilla.retrieve(_RTKey, null, false);
                        var roundedRT: number = Math.round(lastRT);
                        var pointConvertedBlue: number = (8000 - roundedRT);
                        // We now add the rounded reaction time to the screen
                        $(container + _requiredFeedbackZoneSelector).html('<h1>' + '<p style="color: white;">' + 'You earned ' + pointConvertedBlue + ' points' + '</p> ' + '</h1>');
                        // Using gorilla.refreshLayout here will make sure that everything is displayed nicely on the screen
                        gorilla.refreshLayout();
                        gorilla.metric({
                            trial_number: 'pointConvertedBlue',
                            response: pointConvertedBlue
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            if (row.TrialNumer >= 31 && row.TrialNumer <= 60) {
                // Retrieve the reaction time from the store
                var lastRT: number = gorilla.retrieve(_RTKey, null, false);
                var roundedRT: number = Math.round(lastRT);
                var pointConvertedRed: number = (2000 - roundedRT);
                // We now add the rounded reaction time to the screen
                $(container + _requiredFeedbackZoneSelector).html('<h1>' + '<p style="color: white;">' + 'You earned ' + pointConvertedRed + ' points' + '</p> ' + '</h1>');
                // Using gorilla.refreshLayout here will make sure that everything is displayed nicely on the screen
                gorilla.refreshLayout();
                gorilla.metric({
                    trial_number: 'pointConvertedRed',
                    response: pointConvertedRed
                })
            }

            if (row.display == _requiredFeedbackDisplay2) {
                if (screenIndex == _requiredFeedbackScreen2) {
                    if (row.TrialNumer >= 61 && row.TrialNumer <= 90) {
                        // Retrieve the reaction time from the store
                        var lastRT: number = gorilla.retrieve(_RTKey2, null, false);
                        var roundedRT: number = Math.round(lastRT);
                        var pointConvertedBlueK: number = (8000 - roundedRT);
                        // We now add the rounded reaction time to the screen
                        $(container + _requiredFeedbackZoneSelector2).html('<h1>' + '<p style="color: white;">' + 'You earned ' + pointConvertedBlueK + ' points' + '</p> ' + '</h1>');
                        // Using gorilla.refreshLayout here will make sure that everything is displayed nicely on the screen
                        gorilla.refreshLayout();
                        gorilla.metric({
                            trial_number: 'pointConvertedBlueK',
                            response: pointConvertedBlueK
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
            if (row.display == _requiredFeedbackDisplay2) {
                if (screenIndex == _requiredFeedbackScreen2) {
                    if (row.TrialNumer >= 91 && row.TrialNumer <= 120) {
                        // Retrieve the reaction time from the store
                        var lastRT: number = gorilla.retrieve(_RTKey2, null, false);
                        var roundedRT: number = Math.round(lastRT);
                        var pointConvertedRedK: number = (2000 - roundedRT);
                        // We now add the rounded reaction time to the screen
                        $(container + _requiredFeedbackZoneSelector2).html('<h1>' + '<p style="color: white;">' + 'You earned ' + pointConvertedRedK + ' points' + '</p> ' + '</h1>');
                        // Using gorilla.refreshLayout here will make sure that everything is displayed nicely on the screen
                        gorilla.refreshLayout();
                        gorilla.metric({
                            trial_number: 'pointConvertedRedK',
                            response: pointConvertedRedK
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        });`
```

Comment: I know it's a complete dog's breakfast, I am the worst coder ever lol and my experiments are duct tape and string. but it does work! :)